# Display Date & Author Info on Custom Post Type Archive Page

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have created a custom post type called 'articles' with all the same capabilities as the general post type & I am using the same template to display both archives.

The blog page that uses the built in posts shows posted on and by,

[Seen here](http://madebyfactory.com/backstage/)

The custom post type page omits this info

[Seen here](http://andonettes-macbook-pro.local:5757/articles/)

I am lost at this point and don't know what I need to do that's extra, since its using the same code to display both pages.

This is post type function:

```
function post_type_articles() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Articles', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Article', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Articles', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Article Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Article Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Articles', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Articles', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into article', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this article', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Articles list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Articles list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter articles list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Article Description', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'articles' ),
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-aside',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => 'articles',
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'articles', $args );
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'post_type_articles', 0 );

and here is the loop

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php
    if ( is_singular() ) :
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    else :
        the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title archive-header"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
    endif;

    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php factorypress_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php
    endif; ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
</div><!-- /.col-sm-2 -->
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <?php
        the_content( 'more', sprintf(
            wp_kses(
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'factorypress' ),
                array(
                    'span' => array(
                        'class' => array(),
                    ),
                )
            ),
            get_the_title()
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'factorypress' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- /.col-sm-10 -->

    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php factorypress_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

Thanks in advance if you can answer this for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a custom archive template I think you should add the conditional is_post_type_archive()

```
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() || is_post_type_archive( array( 'articles' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Twenty Twenty One Theme we can find in inc/template-tags.php:

```
// Early exit if not a post.
if ( 'post' !== get_post_type() ) {
    return;
}
```

We can override the file to change that code block to:

```
// Early exit if not a post or article.
if ( 'post' !== get_post_type() && 'articles' !== get_post_type() ) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific line in your code prevents the execution of the `factorypress_posted_on` method that displays the post metadata.

```
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
```

That only validates if the post type is **post** not your custom post type **articles**. I think you should replace that particular line of code with this one:

```
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() || 'articles' === get_post_type()) : ?>
```

Comment: Thank you - This has fixed my other issue too - which was the categories not showing custom posts in the archive pages!